# Finding nearest coordinate to other coordinate

Tags: c#, arrays, optimization, location, coordinates

Given an array of geo coordinates and another geo coordinate, I would like to find the nearest coordinate(s) to it.

For example, given the array:

lat               long
52.525782   13.316927
52.526409   13.319083
52.525678   13.320317

And the point: `52.525730, 13.314556`, then the first point `52.525782, 13.316927` will be returned, as it is the closest one.

---

Is the only way of acheiving it is looping through all the array and finding the distance between the points? What happens if the array contains too much coordinates?

Comment: What is the array structure exactly, is lat one array and long another or is it an array like `double[,]`

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre It is one array, just like `double[,]`

Comment: I would rather see a BSP tree - binary space partition.  They take a long time to generate from a set like this, but it will have `O (log n)` search.  Basically given two points there is a line along which they are equidistant, and even if the closest point to your query isn't one of those two, finding which side of that line has the query point can rule out half of the other points and we can skip comparing them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it using LINQ, but the inner workings of LINQ would still loop over your collection. For example:

```
//Your list with coordinates
List<GeoCoordinate> coords = new List<GeoCoordinate>();

//The coord you want to compare
GeoCoordinate crd = new GeoCoordinate();

//Sorts the list based on the proximity of the coords to crd
var sortedCoords = coords.OrderBy(x => x.GetDistanceTo(crd)).ToList();
```

I know it doesn't use an array, but I find using lists is easier.

I think that should work, let me know if it does!

Comment: `OrderyBy` does not sort the list.  It creating an `IEnumerable` that when iterated will give the items from the list in the desired order.

Answer (score 0):

```
    struct coord
    {
        public  double lat;
        public double lon;
    }

    public void Main(coord coord)
    {

        var coords = new[]{ new coord(){lat=1, lon=1} };
        var closest = coords.Min(p => Math.Abs(p.lat - coord.lat) +    Math.Abs(p.lon - coord.lon));


    }
```